# Remove old PIA VPN from Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, vpn

I installed the PIA application in 2015 and now I would like to uninstall it. 
I am having troubles to have a consistent connection, which lasts no more than 30 minutes, so I am now using openvpn with PIA. I would like to try to uninstall the old application and try to install their new one.

The instructions in the [official documentation](https://helpdesk.privateinternetaccess.com/hc/en-us/articles/232054147-How-can-I-uninstall-reinstall-your-application-on-Linux-) do not suit me, because there are no `~/.pia_manager` or `~/.local/share/applications/pia_manager.desktop` to delete:

```
$ ls -a ~/.pia_manager
ls: cannot access /home/asarluhi/.pia_manager: No such file or directory
$ ls -a ~/.local/share/applications/pia_manager.desktop
ls: cannot access /home/asarluhi/.local/share/applications/pia_manager.desktop: No such file or directory

$ whereis .pia_manager
.pia_manager:
$ whereis pia_manager
pia_manager:
```

PIA support is really poor since they removed the live chat. 
I opened a ticket the first of May and a second one the 9th of May but they did not respond. 
I access PIA clicking on the network icon on the top panel, then on VPN Connections. 
I do not know if might be useful: I installed `Ubuntu Mate desktop` and am using it regularly.

Comment: Have you tried $whereis .pia_manager/.pia_manager.desktop in the terminal? (or without the dot in front, I'm not sure why it would be hidden).

Comment: I updated the original message: that file and that directory do not even exist. I suppose that they belong to newer version of the application.

Comment: Whats the name of the package you installed it with? Use {dpkg --get-selections} and search thru all if your not sure, then you can go about removing it.

Comment: I do not remember the name of the package, but surely it has not the pia word. I am reading the output of `dpkg --get-selections`, it will take me ages...

Comment: If it's not in ~/ (home) or .local/share/applications then honestly I do not know where it's installed at...Sry :(

Comment: Found no package name looking related to PIA or Private Internet Access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58978/discussion-between-eodcraft-staff-and-asarluhi).